# Finding Element with Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom, php-curl

I am using cURL to pull a webpage and then loading that into a simple_html_dom.

When I am trying to search for an element with the id "tester" and then return plaintext it is stating "Trying to get property 'plaintext' of non-object in"

The links provided contain will hopefully make this issue more clear,

Page with my code:
https://icerace.co.uk/counter/

Page I am attempting to pull from:
https://creator.zohopublic.com/james.taylor5/order-management-application/view-perma/CounterGP/FhXFwMj4Tah9gXk52AMS7GZFDK45qaV6eF5M4dF50x1WuApG4BeYs2jVh9nCwggm5WfA1MH8bAUy8NxvZ9Onn9Ds6u80vSBEXTTv

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);


# $target is set to whatever web page url I am looking to scrape. I can update it so that if it finds Next or page 2 etc then it will cycle around again.

$target = 'https://creator.zohopublic.com/james.taylor5/order-management-application/view-perma/CounterGP/FhXFwMj4Tah9gXk52AMS7GZFDK45qaV6eF5M4dF50x1WuApG4BeYs2jVh9nCwggm5WfA1MH8bAUy8NxvZ9Onn9Ds6u80vSBEXTTv';
 
# Curl needs a User Agent so that it can emulate the end user browser. I often have to play around with different User Agents before I find one that works reliably.
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36';
 

$ch = curl_init($target);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
 
# The next line is for debugging only and spits out the headers so you can look at the handshakes.
# curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
 
# The next two lines are required for https web sites and are not secure in any way. If I am productionising something then I tighten these up.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 
# This section is only required for Tor, hence why it is commented out
# curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);
# curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy.':'.$port);
 
# This is where the actual web scraping request is made and errors (if any) are flagged.
$initpage = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($initpage);

echo $html->find("#tester")->plaintext;

?>
```

Comment: Did you check if the id is in the response?

Comment: @Thefourthbird when echoing the $initpage it displays the data. However I have realised that the data is stored in this <script> on the raw html 

``` $("#zc-viewcontainer_CounterGP").prepend(pageSanitizer.sanitize('\x3Cp\x20id\x3D\x22tester\x22\x3Etester\x3C\x2Fp\x3E')); ```

How would I go about pulling data from this script as I assume this is not being performed until I echo hence why I cannot find the innerHTML in that element.